# Count в перекрестном запросе postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

помогите пожалуйста! Как сделать перекрестную таблицу в postgresql?
из этого в

| город | заведение |
| --- | --- |
| Москва | Бар |
| Иркутск | Ресторан |
| Братск | Кафе |
| Тбилиси | Бар |
| Москва | Бар |
| Иркутск | Кафе |
| Москва | Кафе |

в это:

| город | Бар | Ресторан | Кафе |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Москва | 2 |  | 1 |
| Иркутск |  | 1 | 1 |
| Братск |  |  | 1 |
| Тбилиси | 1 |  |  |

Так пробую, но нет понимания -_-

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('select city, type_dep, count(type_dep) AS ct
    FROM content.departments
    GROUP by city, type_dep') AS ct ('Бар' int, 'Ресторан' int, 'Кафе' int)
```

нет понимания что делать -_-

Comment: CROSSTAB требует наличия всех категорий (city) и атрибутов (type_dep) и явной сортировки по ним. Так что собирайте в их отдельных подзапросах, CROSSJOIN, потом LEFT JOIN таблицы данных, и только потом агрегация и  CROSSTAB.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT
city,
SUM(IFNULL(place='Бар', 0)),
SUM(IFNULL(place='Ресторан', 0)),
SUM(IFNULL(place='Кафе', 0))
FROM 
city_place
GROUP BY
city
;

Comment: Вообще, это из MySQL, но в Postgres наверняка есть подобное.

Comment: только в mysql это то же не отработает. вы функции перепутали. ifnull тут явно не причем. и вообще было бы достаточно `sum(place='Бар')` для mysql и `sum((place='Бар')::int)` для postgresql. Только вопрос был про функцию postgresql crosstab

Comment: В   MySQL это отлично работает. Прежде. чем написать, я проверил.
И я заметил, что вопрос был про Postgres, и даже не про функцию, а про получение конкретного результата, данный код я привёл в качестве примера - куда копать.

Comment: А, точно. это же вариант coalesce, работать будет. Правда такая проверка излишня, sum сам null пропускает, превращать их в 0 не зачем